# Need to delete random tuples from database in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

We're hiring some third party Test engineers and programmers to help us with some bugs on our website. They would be working on a beta installation of our web application. The thing is that we need to give them a copy of our database, we don't want to give the entire database, its a huge database of companies. So we would want to give them a watered down version of it that has less than a fraction of the actual data -- just enough for making a proper test.

We have data in the following Schema:

```
COMPANIES
ID|NAME|CATEGORY|COUNTRY_ID.....
```

We also have a set number of categories and countries.

The thing is that we don't want the deletion to be too random, basically out of the hundreds of thousands of entries we need to give them a version that has a few hundred entries but such that, you have at least 2-3 companies for each country and category.

I'm a bit perplexed as how to do a select query with the above restriction much less delete.

It's a MySQL database we would be using here. Can this be even done in SQL or do we need to make a script in php or so?

Answer (score 1):

Following select statement will select companies with first 3 `id` in ascending order for each `category, country_id` combination:

```
select id, name, category, country_id
from companies c1
where id in (
              select id
              from companies c2
              where c2.category=c1.category and c2.countr_id=c1.country_id
              order by id
              limit 3
            );
```

Comment: A better approach than mine. :-)

Comment: @Guillem if any two id is sufficient, your solution will be more efficient.

Comment: yes, but since the OP asked in a comment to my answer how to set it to retrieve 3 or more ids, I guess your answer fits his needs better than mine

Answer (score 0):

Not sure my answer will fit your needs since I am doing some assumptions that may be wrong, but you could try the following approach:

```
select category, country_id, min(id) id1, max(id) id2
  from companies
 group by country_id, category
 order by country_id, category
```

This query only gives you 2 company ids instead of 3 and they will be the first and last id that match category and country.

Please note also I wrote this out of my mind and have no MySQL engine to test it.

Hope that helps or at least gives you a hint on how to do it.

Comment: That looks like something I could use, however how can I set it to retrieve 3 or more ids?

Comment: the where clause cross product is redundent. it will work fine without the where clause.

Comment: true, @Raihan, guess I was thinking about something else when I wrote my answer. I'll edit my answer to remove the where clause.